# Using multiple sets of brackets in Javascript to create a type of array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax

Just when I think I'm getting an understanding of the syntax of Javascript, I run into something like this...

I saw this code on the [jqPlot plugin](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php) page.

what kind of array is `[[]]` in javascript?  A nested array?  I thought I understood the double brackets, but in the commented text, I don't understand why there is an extra set (question below).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Our data renderer function, returns an array of the form:
// [[[x1, sin(x1)], [x2, sin(x2)], ...]]
var sineRenderer = function() {
var data = [[]];
for (var i=0; i<13; i+=0.5) {
  data[0].push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
}
return data;
};
```

Why is there an extra set of brackets in this commented statement (the outermost set)?

```
[[[x1, sin(x1)], [x2, sin(x2)], ...]]
```

Thanks

Comment: `[[],[],[]]` is the syntax for an array that contains other arrays. Each inner array in your example contains a number and the sine function of that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are putting in arrays in your `data` array (which creates *arrays inside an array*), doing this would avoid that:

```
var data = [];
for (var i=0; i<13; i+=0.5) {
  data.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
}
```

When you use `[[]]` and then do `data[0]`, you are not utilizing outer array there which jumps in when you output it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a single set of brackets if they said `data.push`. Since the 0-th element of the array is an array, they use `data[0].push` to stuff stuff in it.

Why they need it double-wrapped, no idea without more context.

Comment: yes, the "double-wrapped" is what I was wondering about.  The expression doesn't seem to need three sets of brackets...

Comment: Maybe this example is better context.  Please note the extra outer array (3 bracket sets): `$.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12],[5,13.1],[7,33.6],[9,85.9],[11,219.9]]]);` Taken from http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/usage-txt.html.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a nested array. The `data` array contains an array to which other arrays with value and sine of the value are pushed.

AFAIK, the jQPlot plugin would use every array in `data` to print a new graph. You could for example do

```
function graph(fn, from, to, gap) {
    // creates an array with points
    var res = [];
    for (var i=from; i<to; i+=gap) {
        res.push([i, fn(i)]);
    }
    return res;
}

var data = [
   graph(Math.sin, 0, 13, 0.5),
   graph(Math.cos, 0, 13, 1)
];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Hunter is correct -- it's the syntax for an array containing other arrays. You could also look at doing this as an object, as illustrated here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html.